# can I hide the Acceptable client certificate CA names?

Tags: ssl, apache2.4, apache2.2

Today someone asked me if it was possible to hide the "Acceptable client certificate" list in the SSL connection information. Spontaneously, my answer was no, but according to the RFC it seems to possible.

## openssl s_client -connect www.test170.com:443 -state

### [...]

Acceptable client certificate CA names

### /C=FR/ST=DPT/L=CITY/O=COMPANY/CN=CA_own

[...]

The idea is to hide this informations and let client send the good certificats.

((*...These distinguished names may specify a desired distinguished name
If the certificate_authorities list is empty, then the client MAY
send any certificate of the appropriate ClientCertificateType,
unless there is some external arrangement to the contrary.*))

Someone know how I can hide these informations?
The servers are running with apache2.2 and 2.4.

I try to play with SSLCADNRequestPath path_empty_file but for now it doesn't work.

Comment: *The idea is to hide this informations and let client send the good certificate*  What "good certificate" are you referring to?  Are you using a self-signed certificate and expecting the client to present a certificate from a valid CA?

Comment: A custom automated webservice use the client certificat to connect to backend, this is not a self-signed certificat. I just want to hide this information if possible,  we don't use browser or manually action.